# How to correctly addTextChangeListener in Android xml

Tags: java, android, android-databinding

I've tried to do the same as here:
https://gist.github.com/susemi99/a45ca534cc109271f34e6c992f69f048

so I have my EditText in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<data>
    <import type="test.edu.MyViewModel"/>
    <variable type="MyViewModel" name="viewModel"/>
</data>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

(...)

<EditText 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:addTextChangeListener="@{viewModel.myTextWatcher}"/>

(...)
```

And I have TextWatcher in MyViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel extends BaseObservable {
    public TextWatcher myTextWatcher = new TextWatcher(){
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {}
    };
}
```

I think that I have done it the same as in mentioned link but when I try to compile I get:

> Cannot find the setter for attribute 'app:addTextChangeListener' with parameter type android.text.TextWatcher on android.widget.EditText.

Could you please give me some hints about what is wrong here? I assumed that code I referred is compiling but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figured this out ... It was just a typo. Instead of addText**Changed**Listener I had addText**Change**Listener and to be honest error message wasn't very helpful. Now when I know solution it's obvious but previously I was checking "app" namespace, some @Bind annotations, gradle options and things like that. Maybe it's only me but I think it would be a lot easier with error like:

> android.widget.EditText doesn't have function addTextChangeListener

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way:

```
    EditText editText =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editText.addTextChangeListener(new TextWatcher(){
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {}
    };
```

Instead of writing it in your  `xml` file

Comment: I know but since I'm using MVVM I wanted to avoid findViewById in ViewModel. According to Google: "ViewModel's only responsibility is to manage the data for the UI. It should never access your view hierarchy (...)"

Comment: Setting UI elements in XML is preferabele